# Error in writing a pyspark map into a txt file

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing block multiplication of contents of two files. Finally I try to write the result into a text file, I'm getting the following error,

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o426.saveAsTextFile
```

and

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

**The program:**

```
    import numpy as np
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
    mat = sc.textFile("mat1.txt")
    mat2 = sc.textFile("mat2.txt")

    matFilter = mat.map(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x.split(" ")])
    matFilter2 = mat2.map(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x.split(" ")])

    matgroupp = matFilter.map(lambda x: (x[0], [x[2]])).reduceByKey(lambda p,q: p+q)
    matgroup2 = matFilter2.map(lambda x: (x[1], [x[2]])).reduceByKey(lambda p,q: p+q)

    matInter = matgroupp.cartesian(matgroup2)

    matmul = matInter.map(lambda x: ((x[0][0], x[1][0]), np.dot(x[0][1], x[1][1]))).sortByKey(True)
    matmul.saveAsTextFile("results/res.txt")
```

**Contents of mat1.txt**

```
0 0 10.0
1 0 10.0
```

**contents of mat2.txt**

```
0 0 20.0
0 1 10.0
```

Comment: Problem is somewhere in `matFilter` or `matFilter2` and cannot be reproduced using data and code you've provided.

Comment: Does he code runs without errors for you?

Comment: Yup. I would start with replacing `x.split(" ")` with `x.split()`. Also make sure you don't parse empty lines.